# ASP.NET Text_Change Event

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

In asp.net web application, I am having one textbox and one button in UI. And I set textchanged event for the textbox.

**Textbox_TextChanged Event:** 
When this event fires, web page will display js popup through script manager functionality.

**Button Click Event:**
When this event fires, it will clear the textbox value.

**Now Issue is,**

When I write some text in textbox and without focus out of the textbox, I clicked on Button to clear the values. But Visual studio firing Textbox_TextChanged Event. I need to fire only Button Click Event not a Textbox_TextChanged Event.

**Note :** Here both element's are asp controls.

Please help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: Which language are you coding in vb or c#?

Comment: Also, can you show the markup please

Comment: I am using vb language.

Comment: When you click the button, *that* gets the focus. So the textbox loses the focus and that triggers the TextChanged.

Answer (score 3):

Text_Changed and Button_Click are server events for server controls. That means posting a new http request to the server to get a new http response. By the time these events finish you're looking at an completely new html DOM created from a completely new instance of your Page class. The existing html DOM was destroyed so the new one could take it's place. This is rarely a good idea for something like Text_Changed, that might need to fire repeatedly and respond as fast as a user can type.

You probably want to re-think these to happen entirely in javascript; don't even use the ScriptManager. If you're writing C# or VB.Net to respond to these events, you're in the wrong place. Unfortunately, javascript doesn't have a direct equivalent to Text_Changed, and you'll need to look at the onkeydown, onkeyup, onkeypress, onpaste, oncut, and onmouseup events, any of which *might* cause text to change.

On a UI/UX note, it's also rarely a good idea to push a pop up in front of a user on any possible text change. Users tend not to like it when you interrupt them while they're typing. You might instead want to look at events like onblur and onchange for the popup, and use some other visual indication that things are not right while the user is still working in the textbox... something that won't immediately interrupt them.

Answer (score 0):

Find the textbox control that youre working with and go the properties window (press F4) in visual studio when on this.

Find the lightening icon and click it,

next find the Text Changed event and remove the method \ sub name from this field.

Alternatively in your ASPX markup, you will probably find the event there too...

Also, in your code behind you'll have something like this

```
public sub Text_Changed(...) Handles MyPage.Text_Changed ' (im plucking this out of the air as its been a while since ive worked with VB)
```

You can remove the Handles bit and that would also do it for you